# Popover with picker views not showing correctly

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

This is the code I have for when I try to open a popover that has 2 pickerviews in it.

```
-(void) showPopover {
    NSLog(@"Showing popover.");
    BOOL right = NO;
    BOOL detected = NO;
    int translate = 0;
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"Device is now in Portrait Mode");
        translate += 600;
        detected = YES;
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Device is now in LandscapeLeft Mode ");
        detected = YES;
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Device is now in LandscapeRight Mode");
        right = YES;
        detected = YES;
    }
    else if([[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        NSLog(@"Device is now in PortraitUpsideDown Mode");

        detected = YES;
    }
    if(detected == NO) {
        translate = 0;
        NSLog(@"FREAK ACCIDENT, MATRIX GLITCH");
        //right = YES;
    }

    if(right) translate += 600;
    NSLog(@"Translate is %i", translate);
    UIView *windowView =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]
                                        init];
    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]
                           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 350)];

    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0];
    [pickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 216)];
    [popoverView addSubview:pickerView];
    [secondPickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 0, 450, 216)];
    [popoverView addSubview:secondPickerView];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 250, 200, 50)];
    [button setTitle:@"Go!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [popoverView addSubview:button];

    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
    CGSizeMake(600, 300);


    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                         initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];


    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(70 + translate, 512, 1, 1)
                                            inView:windowView
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                                          animated:YES];


}
```

And if my iPad is laying down, the "matrix glitch" error prints out and causes my popover to not function properly. It also sometimes happen if the device is in a portrait mode.

[image: This is what it looks like when it doesn't function properly]

[image: This is what it looks like when it functions]

The top picture is what it looks like when my popover doesn't function properly, the bottom is it working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` gives you the *physical orientation*
of the device, and there are 7 possible values:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

What you probably want is the current orientation of the *interface*, which you get
by calling the `interfaceOrientation` method of the current view controller.
It has the 4 possible values

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```